# How to block FCM notification popup in foreground iOS App in React-Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have built a Mobile App for Android and iOS platform using React-Native. I have integrated FCM using [enter link description here](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). It works fine on Android. But my iOS App displays notifications in foreground also. I have defined

> "show_in_foreground": false

In FCM message. How can we block notification popups in foreground iOS App.